# ember-moment shows "Invalid date" (only in Safari, both desktop and mobile)

Tags: javascript, date, ember.js, time

**ember-moment** shows "Invalid date" (only in Safari, both desktop and mobile)

```
{{moment-from-now item.bookingDate interval=1000}}
```

P.S.: Firefox, Chrome works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had in my model:

`bookingDate: DS.attr('date'),`

changed to

`bookingDate: DS.attr('string'),`

now works...

---

When I had **item.bookingDate** as **DS.attr('date')**

and **item.bookingDate** had a value **'2016-05-30T09:12:48+0200'**

`{{log 'date: ' item.bookingDate}}`

**chrome:**

`date:  Mon May 30 2016 09:02:48 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

**FireFox**

`date:  Date 2016-05-30T07:02:48.000Z`

**Safari**

`date:  – Invalid Date`

Comment: If you're satisfied with your answer, could you accept it too? Then SO knows it doesn't need any more attention

Comment: @shane I can't right now, but I will (I see message: "You can accept your answer tomorrow")

Comment: I'm so sorry, I was flipping through old questions and I totally missed the date on this one. Thanks!